# Различия FASM и MASM

Tags: ассемблер, masm, fasm

Объясните разницу между ассемблерами FASM и MASM. Изучаю книгу Юрова с практическими алгоритмами на ассемблере, и решил писать их на FASM, потому что говорят, что он дает больше возможностей. Первое, что не понравилось - лишняя секция импорта с мусором внутри, без которого я обходился раньше, и необходимость ставить byte ptr там, где в MASM этого не требовалось. FASM выглядит избыточным.

Наконец, простой пример из книги отрабатывает очень странно:

```
format PE Console 4.0
entry start

include 'win32a.inc'

section '.text' code readable executable

start:
call add_uint

proc add_uint
    mov al, byte ptr a
    add al, 10
    jnc end_p
    adc byte ptr carry, 0
end_p:
    ret 
endp  

exit:
  invoke  ExitProcess, 0

section '.data' data readable writeable
    a       db 255
    b       db 7
    sum     db 0
    carry   db 0

section '.idata' import data readable writeable
    library kernel, 'kernel32.dll'
    import kernel, ExitProcess, 'ExitProcess'
```

Отладчик показывает, что после выполнения ret в процедуре мы попадаем снова в начало процедуры, она отрабатывает второй раз, и только тогда переходим по адресу возврата. Почему так?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы после `call` явно ret поставьте. просто ваш асм сам не подставляет  ret в итоге выполнение продолжается по сегменту кода, где у вас собственно процедура и находится. И лично я от ассемблера ожидаю именно такого поведения - не подставлять ничего от себя, только то что явно написано

Comment: То есть вот так? call add_uint
ret Такого я ни в одном исходнике в интернете не видел. К тому же при этом ret оказывается вне досягаемости процессора, во всяком случае, так показывает отладчик.

Comment: Что значит вне досигаемости. он же в тексте идет сразу после первой инструкции, как процессор может его не выполнить

Comment: Добавил скрин в пост. Там даже адрес возврата остается в стеке.

Comment: А вообще в нормальных исходниках программа должна заканчиваться явно на вызов функции "завершение процесса" операционной системы. В DOS вызывали функцию 4C прерывания 21h. В винде свои способы должны быть. А ret - это скорее загрулшка, в надежде что ОС поймет (т.е. что она в стек положила корректный адрес завершения)

Comment: В коде же написано, что выход в ОС выполняет ExitProcess, 0

Comment: Да, сейчас увидел. До этого не видел, потому как смотрю как процессор. В эту точку в принципе попасть невозможно. Вы делаете call попадаете в свою функцию, из нее возвращаетесь, в точку откуда был call. продолжаете двигаться по коду и опять попадаете в функцию, далее стоит ret. где переход в точку exit ? И зачем вы функицию написали между надачалом программы и точкой exit ?

Comment: Кажется, я догадываюсь. Я думал, что процессор после call add_uint обойдет место, где эта функция определяется, и сразу перейдет к метке exit. Скорее всего это не так, и надо поднять ExitProcess выше, поставить этот вызов сразу после вызова функции.

Comment: Именно так. У процессора же просто набор двоичных байт. он ваших меток не видит. как он может догадаться что дальше функция и ее надо обходить, если вы ему явно jmp не поставили

Comment: "И зачем вы функицию написали между надачалом программы и точкой exit ? " Потому что я не совсем понимаю, как в асме правильно определять функции. В каком месте. Часто их определяют в местах, куда процессор не доберется, потому что к этому моменту произойдет возврат в ОС. А как делают профессионалы?

Comment: Что значит "процессор не доберется". он же вызов увидит и произведет переход

Comment: Имел в виду определение функций ниже места, где происходит выход в систему. Это должно исключать повторное исполнение кода. Вот как в коде из поста: сначала выполняется функция, потом происходит возврат к месту после вызова, и она выполняется снова. Если после call add_uint сразу вызвать ExitProcess, этого не произойдет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Первое, что не понравилось - лишняя секция импорта с мусором внутри

Когда я вижу вопросы по MASM, практически в каждом из них есть куча мусорных `include`. Одно поменялось на другое. На fasm можно писать и без явного указания секции импорта, если, конечно, вам не потребуется вызов функций из библиотек, не входящих в "стандартные".

Вот `hello.asm` из пакета fasm, как видите, ничего "лишнего":

```
format PE GUI 4.0

; example of simplified Windows programming using complex macro features

include 'win32ax.inc' ; you can simply switch between win32ax, win32wx, win64ax and win64wx here

.code

  start:
    invoke  MessageBox,HWND_DESKTOP,"Hi! I'm the example program!",invoke GetCommandLine,MB_OK
    invoke  ExitProcess,0

.end start
```

> необходимость ставить byte ptr там, где в MASM этого не требовалось.

Лучше ставить квадратные скобки, тогда размер явно указывать не придется. В вашем случае обращение к переменным можно изменить на такое:

```
mov al, [a]
...
adc [carry], 0
```

Если обращение идет ко всей переменной, то "размер" указывать не нужно (размер определяется по размеру переменной). Если же идет обращение, например, к одному байту из переменной размера dword, то нужно указать размер byte:

```
mov al, byte [a]
...
a dd 255
```

Обращение по какому-то адресу в fasm обозначается через имя переменной или регистра в квадратных скобках. Я считаю, это более логично, чем то, как это делается в диалекте MASM (если адрес в регистре - то квадратные скобки, если адрес в переменной - то без них).

Подробности, почему решено было сделать именно так, см. в [**Design Principles (or why flat assembler is different?)**](http://flatassembler.net/docs.php?article=design)

Просто смещение (offset) указывается как имя переменной без квадратных скобок, т.е. `mov eax, offset a` в диалекте fasm будет выглядеть как `mov eax, a`.

> Наконец, простой пример из книги отрабатывает очень странно

Конечно, будет странно работать, если поставить функцию сразу после ее вызова. **Код процессором выполняется линейно (пока он не встретит инструкции передачи управления)**. Естественно, что вернувшись после call процессор наткнется на функцию, из которой только что вернулся, и начнет выполнять ее опять.

Если упрощенно, то код самой функции нужно ставить вне кода других функций (выше или ниже, не важно), или делать `jmp` на метку `exit` непосредственно после `call`, раз уж вы завели такую метку, тогда "лишнего" выполнения функции `add_uint` не будет.

**Это не специфика fasm, аналогичный код для MASM будет выполняться так же.**

Ну и, наконец, рабочий пример кода на fasm. Обратите внимание, что через `include` подключен другой файл, который позволяет не указывать явно секцию импорта (секция импорта будет фактически добавлена макросом `.end`):

```
format PE Console 4.0

include 'win32ax.inc'

.code

proc add_uint
    mov al, [a]
    add al, 10
    jnc end_p
    adc [carry], 0
end_p:
    ret 
endp

start:
    call add_uint
    invoke  ExitProcess, 0

.data
    a       db 255
    b       db 7
    sum     db 0
    carry   db 0

.end start
```